# Xorg fails to start after upgrade 15.04 -> 15.10

Tags: 15.04, xorg, intel

I am near to crying with my Acer Travelmate that annoys me ever since I installed a Ubuntu version on it and hope for some help here:
My newest problem is a complete failure of the Xorg giving an unresponsive TTY1 screen.

Xorg.1.log shows no errors

here is a link with all the logs and a lspci -vv output

http://cloud.alexanderkulesza.de/owncloud/index.php/s/8gxc08CMEnX3wlP

Any help will be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks very much in advance!
Alex